# Azure не коннектиться к Facebook, Chatbot

Tags: facebook, azure, bot-framework

После удаления прав администратора на приложение facebook у разработчика, через которого была осуществлена связка facebook - azure -  наш сервер (через аккаунт разработчика были сгенерированы все токены привязки) перестали доходить сообщения от фейсбука до нашего сервера.

Зарегистрировали нового администратора, осуществили следующие действия:

1. в разделе developers.facebook Messenger сгенерировали маркер к странице TestPage - его значение записали в поле Page Access Token * во вкладке Регистрация каналов ботов на Microsoft Azure
2. Там же добавили Идентификатор приложения Facebook, Секрет приложения Facebook, Идентификатор страницы Facebook -  для которой был сгенерирован токен в первом пункте
3. Скопировали URL-адрес обратного вызова для webhook и Токен проверки на azure
4. Сохранили, сохранение прошло успешно
5. В разделе developers.facebook  Messenger - Webhooks проверили галочки на 4-х событиях: message_deliveries, messages, messaging_postbacks, messaging_optins и проверили Страницы, на которые подписано приложение: там TestPage
6. В разделе developers.facebook Webhooks Page в "Edit Subscription" добавил URL и маркер из 3 пункта
7. В разделе azure настройка канала проверили конечную точку обмена сообщениями - она не изменилась

Сообщения по прежнему не доходят до нашего сервера. В чем может быть проблема? Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Может не заплатили разработчику? А то вдруг у вас как в той истории с вваренным ломом...

Comment: Вот только, все аккаунты зареганы на компанию, я не могу понять как могло повлиять удаление админа(я тоже админ с такими же правами как у него). Все ключи созданы на аккаунте компании, но тем админом и они не удалялись вместе с ним.

Comment: На данный момент, мы привязали другое приложение fb, созданное тем же администратором, который был удален. Он был удален и из этого приложения тоже. Иии... Это сработало. Значит проблема с какими то настройками. Будем искать дальше.